# Is there no way to (one way or another) create an owned version of a (Box of) closure in rust?

Tags: rust, copy, closures, lifetime, owned-types

I want to write a `FuncWrapper` struct with a `new` function that takes a (Boxed) closure as parameter, and returns a decorated closure that just adds some boilerplate to the incoming one.  But I also want the returned value to be "owned", to allow for the following (e.g.):

```
fn main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    let a: FuncWrapper<u32>;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        let foo = |x: u32| {print!("{}", x)};                                                                                                                                                                                         
        let b = &Box::new(foo);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        a = FuncWrapper::new(b);                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    let _c = (a.func)(42);                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

That is, I want for the return value of new to be an "owned" value.

Now I recently learned that all closures in Rust (being Trais) must have a lifetime associated with them (and it will default to `'static` if not specified.)  But I suppose its seems that any lifetime for the closure in the FuncWrapper of the return value of `new` will be wrong.

I don't want the lifetime to be that of the incoming reference, because this will be too short.  E.g. the following will *not* work because it the lifetime of the return value is that of the parameter `f_box_ref` which does not live long enough in the case I provide above

```
struct FuncWrapper<'b, DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    func: Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'b>                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
impl<'b, DomainType> FuncWrapper<'b, DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                    
    fn new<F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<'b, DomainType> {                                                                                                                                       
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {                                                                                                                                                                                            
            // ..add some boilerplate then                                                                                                                                                                                            
            (**f_box_ref)(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        };                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        let b = Box::new(new_f);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        FuncWrapper {func: b}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

results in

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:22:18
   |
22 |         let b = &Box::new(foo);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
23 |         a = FuncWrapper::new(b);
24 |     }
   |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
...
27 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `a` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `FuncWrapper<'_, u32>`
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Changing the lifetime of the return parameter to `'static` also seems wrong, since my goal is to *create a new closure inside the `new` function`*, (so how could it be static?) but regardless this:

```
struct FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    func: Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'static>                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
impl<DomainType> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fn new<'b, F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                       
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {                                                                                                                                                                                            
            // ..add some boilerplate then                                                                                                                                                                                            
            (**f_box_ref)(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        };                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        let b = Box::new(new_f);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        FuncWrapper {func: b}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

errors with

```
error[E0759]: `f_box_ref` has lifetime `'b` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/main.rs:7:21
   |
6  |       fn new<'b, F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
   |                                                          ---------- this data with lifetime `'b`...
7  |           let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {
   |  _____________________^
8  | |             // ..add some boilerplate then
9  | |             (**f_box_ref)(a)
10 | |         };
   | |_________^ ...is used here...
11 |           let b = Box::new(new_f);
12 |           FuncWrapper {func: b}
   |                              - ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

The error surprised me since I thought the job of `move` was to capture by value.  At first I thought that I need to dereference the `f_box_ref` first?  But that

```
impl<DomainType> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fn new<'b, F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                       
        let f_box: Box<F> =  *f_box_ref;                                                                                                                                                                                              
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {                                                                                                                                                                                            
            // ..add some boilerplate then                                                                                                                                                                                            
            (*f_box)(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        };                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        let b = Box::new(new_f);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        FuncWrapper {func: b}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

results in

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*f_box_ref` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:7:30
  |
7 |         let f_box: Box<F> =  *f_box_ref;
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^
  |                              |
  |                              move occurs because `*f_box_ref` has type `Box<F>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                              help: consider borrowing here: `&*f_box_ref`
```

Alas, following the hint to "help: consider borrowing here: `&*f_box_ref`" doesn't help either

```
impl<DomainType> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fn new<'b, F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {                                                                                                                                       
        let f_box: &Box<F> =  &*f_box_ref;                                                                                                                                                                                            
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {                                                                                                                                                                                            
            // ..add some boilerplate then                                                                                                                                                                                            
            (*f_box)(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        };                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        let b = Box::new(new_f);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        FuncWrapper {func: b}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

errors with

```
error[E0759]: `f_box_ref` has lifetime `'b` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/main.rs:7:31
   |
6  |     fn new<'b, F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_box_ref: &'b Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
   |                                                        ---------- this data with lifetime `'b`...
7  |         let f_box: &Box<F> =  &*f_box_ref;
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ ...is used here...
...
13 |         FuncWrapper {func: b}
   |                            - ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

so obviously we're still not returning anything like a new owned closure, and any choice for the lifetime of the returned closure seems arbitrary and wrong.

What I'm trying to do here seems like it should be common.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you want `FuncWrapper` to _own_ the wrapped closure, it must take in the wrapped closure by _value_, not by reference.

Comment: @EvilTak How is FuncWrapper taking in the wrapped closure by reference?

Comment: Since `new_f` in `FuncWrapper::new` uses `f_box_ref`, the closure object generated by the compiler for `new_f` contains a copy of the `f_box_ref` reference (the `move` keyword makes no difference, as immutable references are `Copy`). `new_f` (and by extension the returned `FuncWrapper`) is thus inherently tied to `f_box_ref`'s lifetime. You are returning a new "owned" closure, but that "owned" closure contains a reference to the wrapped closure.

Comment: @EvilTak Yes, I suspected that the returned value was somehow still being tied to `f_box_ref`, but part of my question is how to get around that.   So when you say "it must take in the wrapped closure by value," what exactly are you suggesting I do?

Comment: Have `FuncWrapper::new` take the closure by value (`f_box: Box<F>`) instead of by reference. That, combined with the use of the `move` keyword to create `new_f`, will ensure that `f_box` (the wrapped closure) will be _moved into_ `new_f`, and the resulting closure will completely own the wrapped closure.

Comment: @EvilTak Is that the only way?  I guess I was thinking that there *should* be a way to do this even w/ just a reference to the Box.  E.g. this is unproblematic for other types where we can clone, and indeed is a common pattern since we may want to do something else w/ the variable after passing it in (and so don't want to move it in).  Is there really no way to do this by just passing in to new a reference?

Comment: Closures _can_ be `Clone`able [in some cases](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits). You could always restrict `FuncWrapper::new` to only take references to `Clone`able closures by adding the `Clone` bound to the type parameter `F`. No way to do what you want without cloning or copying unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straight forward, to get an owned type from a reference you have 3 options that come to mind immediately:
`Copy`, `Clone` or `ToOwned`.
`ToOwned` is a little more advanced since it can change the type as well and since `Copy` requires `Cloned` I'll focus on the later.

To get an owned `Fn` from a `&Box<Fn>` you can just call `clone()`:

```rust
impl<DomainType> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
    fn new<F: Fn(DomainType) + Clone + 'static>(f_box_ref: &Box<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
        let f_box = f_box_ref.clone();
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {
            // ..add some boilerplate then
            (f_box)(a)
        };
        let b = Box::new(new_f);
        FuncWrapper { func: b }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have an upvote. 

In my defense, I tried exactly this w/o the `+ Clone` and instead of giving an error about not being able to clone, it gives  "`f_box_ref` has lifetime `'_`  but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement"

Unfortunately my closures will need to capture other environment variables (the example I gave was simplified) so I'm not sure I will be able to satisfy the requirements for `Clone`.

Comment: Well references implement `Clone` too, unfortunately it's not always obvious what `.clone()` is actually cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not `FnMut`, just `Fn` maybe you can use an `Rc` instead of `Box`? You can always clone an `Rc`

```
use std::rc::Rc;

impl<DomainType> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
    fn new<F: Fn(DomainType) + 'static>(f_rc: Rc<F>) -> FuncWrapper<DomainType> {
        let new_f = move |a: DomainType| {
            // ..add some boilerplate then
            (f_rc)(a)
        };
        let b = Box::new(new_f);
        FuncWrapper { func: b }
    }
}
```